# design Asp.Net MVC 5 layered solution for horizontal scaling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have been reading about using azure for asp.net solutions and I am sold. I have questions about a ton of stuff but I would like to know how to scale a layered application. I read in a book that we could for performance and scaling sake we can have our models, business logic and DbContext in a separate project and that this project can be on a separate server. So I guess my question is can a .NET class library be hosted in IIS? how would doing this scale and give me an advantage. Sorry I am an advanced beginner so you will need to bear with me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't host just a class library technically.

Having them in a separate project is not done for scaling reasons. It's done so you can reuse the models in unit tests etc.

One thing you can do of course is to create an API project, which will be hosted in e.g. Azure App Service. Then you can build an MVC project that then uses this API through HttpClient and the like. This separates your front-end and back-end allowing both apps to scale independently depending on their load. This would of course require them to be in separate App Service Plans in Azure as otherwise they share the server instances. The plan can be changed later though, so you can move them to a separate plan later and start with a common one for now.

If you want to break down your app into even smaller pieces, I would advise looking into microservices architecture.